# Gradle multiple jars from single source folder with different dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am working on one gradle script where I need to compile the source code two times but with different dependencies.

First time I need create a jar file with dependencies for e.g.
 compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"

and next jar file should compile with other dependencies for e.g.
 compile "a.b:b:3.4"

How we could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable for the dependency string. It might be convenient to use a command line parameter.

```
dependencies{
  compile switchableDependencyFromCommandLine
}
```

and then run:

```
./gradlew someTask -PswitchableDependencyFromCommandLine=a.b:b:3.4
```

It might also be a good idea to provide a default value if the -P parameter is not provided, just for script robustness.

Comment: The dependencies could be more and job will run from jenkins so cann't use variable.Is it possible everything inside the gradle script

Comment: You should put that information in your question so you can get a more accurate answers then. Also, you can use command parameters in jenkins.